# how to add class to particular `li` tag in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Im trying to add class on mouseover in `li` tag on `ngFor` loop. but when mouseover the `li` tag all the `li` tag `btn-success` class is added. how to add class to particular `li` tag in ngFor loop?.

```
<li class="hhwtmainmenu" *ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let i=index; " [class.btn-success]="mouseOvered" (mouseout)="mouseOvered=false" (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true">
    {{headermenu.title}}
</li>
```

Comment: you have to also add second condition as per your requirement like  [class.btn-success]="mouseOvered && xxxx==yyyyy"

Comment: @SandipPatel, where it is come from `&& xxxx==yyyyy`?

Comment: you have to add your logic like that

Comment: `&& xxxx==yyyyy` is your conditional logic, on which `item` you want to add class.

Comment: @SandipPatel, can you explain more?

Comment: @SangwinGawande, like this `[class.btn-success]="mouseOvered && i==index"`? can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, but depends on which `item` you want to add condition. if that item index is `3` then `index` becomes `3`

Comment: @SangwinGawande, its not working

Comment: Wait. I'll post  as answer.

Comment: @Sangwin: I have already post an answer, rest OP has to write logic as per requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an excellent solution but will do the trick for you.

```
<ul><li class="hhwtmainmenu"
  *ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let i=index; "
  [class.btn-success]="selectedIndex === i"
  (mouseout)="removeIndex(i)"
  (mouseover)="setIndex(i)">
{{headermenu.title}}
</li>
</ul>
```

For the methods in you component file:

```
  setIndex(index: number) {
this.selectedIndex = index;
}
removeIndex(index: number) {
this.selectedIndex = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

HTML :

```
<li class="hhwtmainmenu" *ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let i = index "  [ngClass]="{'btn-success': (i == 2)}" (mouseout)="mouseOvered=false" (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true">
{{headermenu.title}}
</li>
```

Style :

```
.btn-success:hover {
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `(i == 2)` this is the condition.

Comment: class is not added to li tag. this is my code `<li class="hhwtmainmenu" *ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let i = index " [ngClass]="{'btn-success': (i == 2)}" (mouseout)="mouseOvered=false" (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true">`

Comment: Only print `(i == 2)` and check its value, `true` or `false`.

Comment: i tried with `(i == 0)`. its working for first `li` tag and its not working for second `li`. tag

Comment: I think your `i` is `undefined`. that is why it is working for `0` use `index as i` instead of `let i = index`

Comment: no. `i` value is correct. i declared `let i = index`

Comment: use `index as i` instead of `let i = index`

Comment: like this `*ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let index = index " [ngClass]="{'active': (mouseOvered && index == 0)}"` ?

Comment: No that's wrong : `*ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; index as i " [ngClass]="{'active': (index == 2)}"` & in style.css `active:hover{color:blue}`

Comment: getting error `Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForAs' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("
                     </li>

                     <li class="hhwtmainmenu" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let index as i" [ngClass]="{'active': (mouseOvered && i"): HeaderComponent@61:46`

Comment: Try : `*ngFor="let headermenu of headermenus.header; let i = index " [ngClass]="{'active': (index == 2)}"` & in style.css as `.active:hover{color:blue}`

Comment: Well I'm out of options, the answer is correct and working in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use binding by angular only when there's some business logic required for deciding that property (viz. CSS class in your case). Binding should be avoided as it causes over computation by angular due to its change detection and lifecycle hooks.

As in your case you just want style to be added on hover you can use :hover class for your li elements.

```
.hhwtmainmenu:hover {
    // The Styling you added in btn-success class
}
```

Though my approach doesn't uses any angular directive but it will improve performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
have a look at this this 

app.component.html

<div class="ul">
  <li
   *ngFor="let number of numbers;let i=index"
    [class.selectedd]="i===selectedIndex"

    (click)=toggleClass(i)>
    {{number}} {{i}}
  </li>
</div>


app.component.ts

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  selected = false;

  selectedIndex = -1;

  numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

  toggleClass(index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex === index ? -1 : index;
  }
  getCondition() {
    return this.selected;
  }
}

app.component.css

.selectedd{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you have to also add second condition as per your requirement like  **[class.btn-success]="mouseOvered && xxxx==yyyyy"**

Example : suppose you wants to add class only when headermenu title is "test" then you have to write above logic as below.

```
[class.btn-success]="mouseOvered && headermenu.title=='test'"
```

Comment: the titles are dynamic.

Comment: you have to build and write your logic, how i know your logic where you wants to apply class

Comment: i tried with your logic but not working. `[class.btn-success]="mouseOvered && headermenu.title=='test'"`

Comment: is any of your headermeny title is 'test'?, have you check properly?

Comment: not possible given solution is 100% right, try with removing your own condition like this: [class.btn-success]="headermenu.title=='test'"

Comment: can i know reason for down vote? so I can improve answer